# Place a tabular and an image in the same float, forcing a table and a figure to be on the same page

Tags: tables, floats

I know that I can place two `tabular`s in a single `table` environment and reference both tabulars using the `cref` package, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    A & B\\
    C & D\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table A}\label{tab:a}
  
  \vspace*{2\floatsep}

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    W & X\\
    Y & Z\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table B}\label{tab:b}
\end{table}

Refer to \cref{tab:a} and \cref{tab:b}.

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe1]

That is one way to force two `tabular`s to be on the same page.

Now, however, I want to force a `tabular` and an image to be on the same page.  Is it possible to place a `tabular` and an image in the same float?  I tried the following (similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134172/15622)):

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    E & F\\
    G & H\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table C}\label{tab:c}

  \vspace*{2\floatsep}

  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Figure A}\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

Refer to \cref{tab:c} and \cref{fig:a}.

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe2]

However, the labels/captions are incorrect; "Figure 1" should be "Table 1".  What can I do?

Comment: you have already loaded caption package so you can do `\captionof{table}>my caption}` to put a table caption in a figure or `\captionof{figure}{...]` to put a figure in a table.  Note that in either case the floats may float out of order.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I force the floats to stay in order?

Comment: You have also the option of make two floats, but change the options to  maintain they together, including ignoring the rules (e.g., if the second top float is a bit large for the LaTeX taste,  simply a `[!]` could help) o change the rules (for instance, allowing more than two top floats). See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) for more about this.

Comment: You can put all tables in figure environments then all figures will stay in source order if you put most tables in table environments but some in figures then my float past each other (but same is true of `longtable` or `[H]` tables, a table environment may float past them too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption)'s `\captionof{<float type>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    E & F\\
    G & H\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table C}\label{tab:c}

  \vspace*{2\floatsep}

  \begingroup
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{Figure A}\label{fig:a}
  \endgroup
\end{table}

Refer to \cref{tab:c} and \cref{fig:a}.

\end{document}
```

The grouping of the `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}` is not really needed here, but it is advised to put `\captionof` inside a group since it changes macros locally. It already resides within a group provided by the `table` environment and is placed last inside the float, so it wouldn't affect anything if you remove the `\begingroup`...`\endgroup`.

Answer (score 3):

The `xcoffins` package was conceived to place stuff on a page specifying the relative positions with each other, and where in the page. In this case you want a table and a figure stacked vertically and treated as a single element.

In this solution there are 4 coffins (boxes with handles) defined, one for the table, a second for the figure and the last two for their respective captions.

I chose the width of the Table and Figure coffins to be `0.4\textwidth`. The captions coffins will  adjust their width to their respective parents-width, automatically.

The assembly process are just three steps: join the top center of `CaptionTablex` to the bottom center of the `Tablex`, with an Y offset of  `-\floatsep`, then repeating the action for the Figure and its caption. (Shouldn't the caption be above the table?)

Finally the full assembly is typeset in the current insertion point, usually the left side of the text area, over the baseline.

This full set is a text object, not a float, and therefore immune to the TeX float mechanism. That means that can be inserted before or after any text, in a margin, etc; or even outside the text area.

`[hc,b]` refers to a point at the bottom and the horizontal center of the box,
`[hc,t]` refers to point at the top and the horizontal center of the box.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[%
expansion = false ,
tracking = smallcaps ,
letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcoffins} % added

\begin{document}

% allocate  
\NewCoffin\Tablex
\NewCoffin\Figx
\NewCoffin\CaptionTablex
\NewCoffin\CaptionFigx  

%fill
\SetVerticalCoffin\Tablex{0.4\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        E & F\\
        G & H\\
    \end{tabular}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\Figx{0.4\textwidth}{%
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\CaptionTablex{\CoffinWidth\Tablex}{\captionof{table}{Table C \label{tab:c}}} 
\SetVerticalCoffin\CaptionFigx{\CoffinWidth\Figx}{\captionof{figure}{Figure A \label{fig:a}}}

 % assembly
%\JoinCoffins\Tablex[hc,t]\CaptionTablex[hc,b](0pt,-0.5\floatsep ) % X Y offsets caption above table
\JoinCoffins\Tablex[hc,b]\CaptionTablex[hc,t](0pt,-0.5\floatsep ) % X Y offsets caption below table
\JoinCoffins\Tablex[hc,b]\Figx[hc,t](0pt,-\floatsep ) % X Y offsets
\JoinCoffins\Tablex[hc,b]\CaptionFigx[hc,t](0pt,-0.5\floatsep ) % X Y offsets

%typeset
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Tablex(0pt, 0pt) % X Y offsets not needed here
\bigskip

Refer to \cref{tab:c} and \cref{fig:a}.

\end{document}
```

[image: bounty]

I expect the readers to became aware of the potency and potential of this tool--method, which in a very simple way is capable of dealing with a many different elements: tables, text, figures, plots, rules, etc; and accommodate them using the relative position one to the other, instead of an absolute coordinate system.

I works like a layout design program (almost, no GUI) by filling the boxes with its content, each with his own color, font type and size and graphic material, and then arrange and align them according the design specs.
*There is a clear separation between content and graphic design.*

The float mechanism is great until it puts your material in another page, and then you have to turn the page (in a printed document) to see the figure or the table.
As it is not a float, it offers the possibility of locating any set of elements in an exact place in a document, the subject of many questions in this forum, without further packages.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this easy solution with `floatrow`, which lets you have  table and figure side by side, with their respective cations:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small}, labelsep=quad, labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[expansion=false, tracking=smallcaps, letterspace=40]{microtype}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
\begin{floatrow}\TopFloatBoxes
\killfloatstyle \ttabbox[2\FBwidth]{\begin{tabular}{ll}
    E & F\\
    G & H\\
  \end{tabular}}
{\caption{Table C}\label{tab:c}}
%
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}}
 {\caption{Figure A}\label{fig:a}}
 \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

Refer to \cref{tab:c} and \cref{fig:a}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a `floatcolumn` package?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can have several consecutive floatrow's.