# How can I move my table to left of the page?? it is in the middle I want it closer to the left

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table} [hbp!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l |l | c }
\textbf{Sharpe Index} & \textbf{Values} \\
 \hline \hline
$\mu$  &0.01839318\\
$\sigma$& 0.002537097\\
Max & 0.02531137\\
Min & 0.01269837 \\
Median & 0.01829877\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistic Moments}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: With that cropped image and the broken MWE is hard try to guess your final goal, but i will suggest anyway: Do not the decenter table but center the figure, or put both side-by side  as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133797/11604).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}` to your preamble and remove `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` from your code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} [hbp!]
\begin{tabular}{l |l | c }
\textbf{Sharpe Index} & \textbf{Values} \\
 \hline \hline
$\mu$  &0.01839318\\
$\sigma$& 0.002537097\\
Max & 0.02531137\\
Min & 0.01269837 \\
Median & 0.01829877\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistic Moments}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```